# I am trying to start the podman.service but i am getting a message saying "podman.service failed" when i do systemctl status podman

Tags: linux, service, virtual-machine, podman

I am trying to start the `podman.service` but i am getting a message saying "podman.service failed" when i do `systemctl` status `podman`. My `journalctl` logs are also saying "podman.service: main process exited" and "unit `podman.service` entered failed state" For context i am running a virtual machine using centos 7.
I have already tried making sure podman is installed and enabled, I have also created a file named "podman.service" under the /usr/lib/systemd/system directory and put in the following information into the file

```
[Unit]
Description=Podman Container Engine
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman daemon
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then I saved the file and made it executable by running the following commands:

```
sudo chmod +x podman.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

I also created the podman.socket file using the following commands

sudo mkdir -p /run/podman

sudo chown -R root:root /run/podman

sudo touch /run/podman/podman.sock
```

I ran these commands as root and also tried with `sudo`,
also when I do `systemctl` status `podman.service` it says `(code=exited, status=125`) in all red.
I am not sure what else to do as I am still getting those same error messages, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.